# Download image files from wms service

Tags: wms, image, download

I'm having trouble getting (georf'ed or not) images from here:

http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/forestobjections/

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having? Have you contacted the website owners?

Answer (score 4):

Though you mention WMS server in the title and the URL you give includes the word WMS.  The URL itself points to some sort of portal, which may or may not be using WMS to provide some of the data.

The portal seems to be working, in that different layers load at different scales, and you can get information popups. I am able to use the portal to load data, I can't read Greek so I can't see if there is some download function, that isn't working.

[image: Greek map portal]

By looking at the web traffic whilst I used the portal I can see that the requests that retrieve the data in the layers I loaded are not from a WMS (do not follow the WMS specification).